# RewriteCond /param/ -> GET

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт со старыми урлами типа

```
site.ru/shop_content.php/coID/11
site.ru/index.php/cat/1/filter_id/53/cPath/1/sort/name/direction/desc
```

как то можно превратить его в такой вид?

```
site.ru/shop_content.php&coID=11
site.ru/index.php?cat=1&filter_id=53&cPath=1&sort=name&direction=desc
```

Comment: обычно люди просят обратный процесс провести ), вы ничего в вопросе не перепутали?

Comment: нет) в проведении обратного процесса куча инфы в сети, а в обратку не нашел

Answer (score 1):

А вот так:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.+)/(.+)$ $1?$2=$3 [QSA,L,R=301]
```